# How to log exceptions on any server or online location

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I want to log/store exceptions somewhere online (not on desktop) so that everyone can access it. I am working on Windows ASP.net MVC.

I don't have a database to store error data. Just thinking if you suggest me something like Firebase Crashlytics, HockeyApp (for mobile apps) or can I store in Github account.

I tried sending exceptions through SMTP mail but my machine has firewall related issue so that is not working and doesn't have any drive like C or D, due to restrictions.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: That really depends on what environment your application is running in and where it needs to store the data. I'm afraid that we can't answer such a broad question as ultimately you will need to determine where, when and with what?

Comment: @ChrisBD - As I mentioned this is asp.net application(website). To store the logs I do not have db. Just thinking if anything there like firebase crashlytics, or I can log exceptions to my github account, hokeyapp(for mobile app) etc. I am asking what will be the better or at all possible? Thank you.

Comment: are you looking for complete services, like aws cloudwatch, or something like NLog that lets you specify arbitrary log targets (including cloudwatch) ?

Comment: @JonasH - I am looking for free service. Where I can login and see the exceptions. I am not sure NLog providing file facility to store online somewhere(I cant store file in my machine as there is no drive C and D and my application going to run on client on m/c ). Nlog mail again they are using smtp. Thank you.

Comment: There are aws free tier for various services, including cloudwatch. I would guess their competitors have similar offers.

Comment: @JonasH - Thanks for information. I tried creating aws account they are asking payment detail(but saying 1 year free) then I moved back. Need to check with something else as you said. If you have idea about other service providers please suggest.

Comment: If you want software recommendations I would suggest https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Software and Service recommendations are discuraged on stackOverflow. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource